# determining if a field exists on a form

Tags: javascript

I have a form field (a series of checkboxes) that's being created dynamically from a database, so it's possible that the field will not exist on the form (if there are no matching values in the database). I have some code that needs to execute based on whether the field exists, and pull in the values that are selected if it does exist. I can't seem to get javascript to acknowledge that this field exists, though. Here's what I've tried:

```
function displayAction(){
    var f = document.adminForm;
    var a = f.action;

    if(f.prefix.value!="-") {
        a = a + '&task=callExclusionDisplay&prefix=' + f.prefix.value;
    }
    else {
        var exclusions = document.getElementById("exclusions");
        if (exclusions != null){
            alert("exclusions set");
            a = a + '&task=callExclusionCreate&prefix=' + f.prefix.value + '&exclusions=' + exclusions.join();
        }
    }
    alert('after if, action is ' + a);
}
```

The code never passes the if statement checking to see if exclusions is not null, even though when I look at the page there are a number of checkboxes named exclusions (with the id also set to exclusions). Is the issue with !=null because it's a group of checkboxes, rather than a single form element? How can I get this to work? If I skip the test for null, the code throws errors about exclusions not being defined if the database doesn't return any matching values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `document.getElementById`, but form elements have a name.
Try `f.elements.namedItem("exclusions")` instead of `exclusions != null`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple elements in the same page cannot share an `id` attribute (ie. `id` must be unique or unset). As well, though some (older) browsers erroneously collect elements whose name matches the ID being looked for with `getElementById`, this is invalid and will not work cross-browser.

If you want to get a group of elements, you can give them all the same `name` attribute, and use [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementsByName) to get the group. Note that the result of that will be a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList) which is kind of like an array in that it can be iterated over.

Comment: They do all have the same name, and I've tried getElementsByName and it doesn't work. No errors, it just doesn't evaluate as true so the code inside the if never runs.

Comment: @EmmyS if you `alert(document.getElementsByName('exclusions'))`, what is the result?

Comment: @EmmyS you need to remove any duplicate ID's from your page.  Make sure all of your elements that have the ID specified are not duplicated. Even if it is the same kind of element.

Answer (score 0):

Do all the checkboxes have the same id == exclusions?
If yes, then you must first correct that.

Before you do so, did you try checking the first checkbox and see if the if condition goes through?

Comment: id must be always unique, failing which the first element in the DOM matching the id is selected. that is why i asked you try selecting the first checkbox to see if the condition goes through.

you could try what @lekensteyn suggested, not sure about it though.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one element with the id "exclusions" it will screw up the functionality of getElementById.   I would remove the duplicate "exclusions" ids from all of your elements and use getElementByName() instead, and give your group of checkboxes the name="exclusions" instead.

Edit:
But there is a much simpler way using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and it gives you some cross browser compability guarrantee.  To do the same thing with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) do this:

```
var checkBoxesExist = $('[name=exclusions]').count() > 0;
```

Or if you have given your elements unique ID's then you can do this:

```
var checkbox1exists = $('#checkBox1').count() > 0;
```

Comment: @EmmyS Check View source of your page in your browser.  Are there any ID's for any elements that appear more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Each element must have a unique ID.

Then, you can check just like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('exclusions1')) {
    //field exists
}
```

Or if you need to loop through a bunch of them:

```
for (x=0; x<10; x++) {
    if (document.getElementById('exclusions' + x)) {
        //field X exists
    }
}
```