# Determine if frame exists as a condition in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, frame, nightwatch.js

I need to check if a pop-up exist(which opens in an iframe), then i will execute some chunk of code (switch to that frame, enter some data, click Continue button). 
While searching for a solution, i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568591/determining-if-a-field-exists-on-a-form) that is 90% the same as mine, except it validates the existance of a specific element. In my case, i cannot check the element until i switch to the new frame.

So instead of `document.getElementById` i should find something similar for frames. Is there anything like this that i can use in Nightwatch?

```
var popup = browser.getElementById("myFrameId");
if (popup!= null){
        //chunck of code
    }
```

I have also tried with something like mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/121) but with no successs, it seems i cannot pass the frame id to any of this functions:

```
var popup =0;
do {
    popup =0;
    klarnaForm.waitForElementVisible('iframe #klarna-fullscreen-iframe',5,false,function (result) {
            if(result.value) {
                changeFrame('pop-up');
                changeFrame('klarna');
                klarnaForm.continueKlarna();
                popup = 1;
                }
        });
} while (popup);
```

Answer (score 0):

get popup value outside of the callback, is that what you want?if yes, try this one :

```
var popup =0;
    browser.waitForElementVisible('iframe #klarna-fullscreen-iframe',5,false,function (result) {
            if(result.value) {
                changeFrame('pop-up');
                changeFrame('klarna');
                klarnaForm.continueKlarna();
                popup = 1;
                }
        })
         .perform(function(browser,done){
           console.log(popup); // popup will be 1 if the 'if statement' above was true
             // do your chuck code here.
          });
```

ps: currently ,the api `.perform` doesnt support page-object, that is why we must stay with `browser` object.

Comment: no, i want to be able to link my code to the existance of that pop-up. IF and only IF that popup exists, perform those actions. but i don't how to translate that IF into code.

Comment: problem with this piece of code is that waitForElementVisible doesn't seem to work for frames.